# Unexpected Pre-order traversal of Tree

Tags: c, data-structures

When I am executing my code, I am getting the wrong result for a pre-order traversal of my binary tree. I am expecting that my program print this pre-order 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2-> 6 -> 7 -> 8. I am not able to point out my mistake in code. Please tell me where I have made a mistake.

This is my input and output (a sample run):

```
ENTER THE NODE DATA
5
ENTER YOUR CHOICE
ENTER THE NODE DATA
4
ENTER YOUR CHOICE
ENTER THE NODE DATA
6
ENTER YOUR CHOICE
ENTER THE NODE DATA
3
ENTER YOUR CHOICE
ENTER THE NODE DATA
7
ENTER YOUR CHOICE
ENTER THE NODE DATA
2
ENTER YOUR CHOICE
ENTER THE NODE DATA
8
ENTER YOUR CHOICE
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 ->
```

This is the code for creating the binary tree and printing a pre-order traversal of the tree.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node {
               int data;
               struct node *right;
               struct node *left;
            }  *tmp  = NULL;

typedef struct node NODE;

  NODE *root = NULL;
  NODE *child, *new_node;

 void preorder(NODE *t)
{
     if(t != NULL)
     {
            printf("%d -> ",t->data);
            preorder(t->left);
            preorder(t->right);
     }//IF
 } 
  int main ()
  {
      char choice;
      do{
           new_node = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
           printf("ENTER THE NODE DATA \n");
           scanf("%d",&new_node -> data);

           new_node -> right = NULL;
           new_node -> left  = NULL;

           if(root == NULL)
           {
                   root = new_node;
                   tmp  = new_node;
           }//IF

           else
           {
               child = new_node;

               while(1)
               {
                       if(child -> data < tmp -> data)
                       {
                             if(tmp -> left == NULL)
                              {
                                  tmp -> left = new_node;
                                  break;  
                              }//if2  
                              tmp  = tmp -> left;
                       }//if1

                       if(child -> data > tmp -> data)
                       {
                           if(tmp -> right == NULL)
                           {
                               tmp -> right = new_node;
                               break;
                           }//if4
                           tmp = tmp -> right;
                       }//if3
               }//while
           }//else
           printf("\n ENTER YOUR CHOICE \n");
           choice = getch();
        }//do
         while(choice != 'n');
         preorder(root);
         getch();
         return 0;
  }//main
```

Comment: Note that the `.` and `->` (dot and arrow) operators bind very tightly and should not have spaces around them.

Comment: The inconsistent indentation makes this code rather hard to follow.

Comment: You should avoid global variables whenever possible. None of the four variables defined needs to be global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In do while add the following statement.

```
else {
child=new_node;
tmp=root;
...
...
}
```

After every loop, tmp value will be changed. We have to check the new value with the root itself.

Comment: Still I am getting same output.What to do

Comment: @user2671906 Where you placed that condition?

Comment: if(root == NULL)
           {
                   root = new_node;
                   tmp  = root;
           }

Comment: yes I change to this and now my code is working ,thanks man I stuck with this problem from last week. How I improve myself to avoid such mistake in my code.

Comment: Do some paper work with the input before your code. In that if you maintain the all values then you can easily implement the code without these kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't reset `tmp` to be the root in every iteration.

Note that there is no need for variable `child` at all, as its value is completely identical to that of `new_node`.

Comment: Where I have to set tmp to be the root in every iteration.